# "My uncle's visits"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The phrase: "My uncle's visits" mean:

- my uncle visits somebody (my uncle is a visitor)
- my uncle receives visits from other persons (that persons are the visitors)

The context allows both meanings? Else, what is the correct usage?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a person's visits can be those made or received. The context should make things clear.

> My uncle's visits **from** his daughter made him happy.
>   The visits
>   which my uncle **received from** his daughter made him happy.
>
> My uncle's visits **to** his friend made him happy.
>   The visits which
>   my uncle **made to** his friend made him happy.

Comment: Your first example is kinda marginal to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just the phrase: "My Uncle's Visits" - when used without any other qualifiers, denote the visits your uncle made.  (That would make for a dandy book title - could be celebrated as a classic in 50 years).

If you qualify with other words (as posted by Michael Harvey) - the meaning would be determined by the context of the sentence.